# How to generate scatter plot from the vector values in each row for PCA?

Tags: matplotlib, pyspark, pca

I have successfully created label and feature vectors and am able to apply pca analysis on it but what happens is that the column generated is of datatype vector and each row is a vector. How do I plot a scatter plot for the pca components

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# from matplotlib.pyplot import matplotlib
pca = PCA(k=2, inputCol="scaledFeatures", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(df2)
result = model.transform(df2).select("pcaFeatures")
result.show(truncate=False)
result.printSchema()
sum(model.explainedVariance)
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
pcaFeatures                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
|[0.9636424850516068,0.3313811478935345]  |
|[0.8373410183626885,0.3880024159205323]  |
|[-0.10845002652578276,0.6564023408615134]|
|[-0.479560942670008,1.1082617061107987]  |
|[0.9576794865061756,0.2714643678687506]  |
|[0.7879027918969023,0.5145147352059565]  |
|[0.5124304692668866,-0.1917648708243116] |
|[-0.7369547765884317,1.0356901001261056] |
|[-0.10282606527163515,0.671822806010155] |
|[1.0661514594145962,0.3285042864447201]  |
|[-0.32474294634018674,0.8134787300694735]|
|[-0.2109752165189983,0.7625432021333773] |
|[0.9643915702012056,0.3276715407315949]  |
|[0.8970032005901719,0.3514814197107741]  |
|[0.47244006359864477,0.6034483574148226] |
|[0.7840860892766188,0.421458958932977]   |
|[-0.7640855001185652,1.117508731487764]  |
|[0.5078194714105165,0.5364599694359978]  |
|[1.020982108328857,0.36510796039610344]  |
|[-0.6823665987365033,-0.5902523648089859]|
+-----------------------------------------+
only showing top 20 rows

root
|-- pcaFeatures: vector (nullable = true)

0.4127855508907272
```